# how to write regex for below format using python

Tags: python

I want to validate below data using regex and python.
Below is the dump of the data which Can be stored in string variable

```
Start 0  .......... group=..... name=...... number=.... end=(digits)
Start 1  .......... group=..... name=...... number=.... end=(digits)
Start 2  .......... group=..... name=...... number=.... end=(digits)
Start 3  .......... group=..... name=...... number=.... end=(digits)

Where ......is some random data need not to validate
...
..

Start 100  .......... group=..... name=...... number=.... end=(digits)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What code have you written so far?  This is not a "Please write my program for me.com" web site.  What Specific question do you have?   What regex did you try?  What went wrong?  What error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `r'(Start \d+.*?group=.*?name=.*?number=.*?end=\d+)*'`.